# TextBlock with ScrollView makes the content blur

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, windows-phone, scrollviewer

I have a Slide transition with text in that.

Code:

```
SlideTransition slideTransition = new SlideTransition();
                slideTransition.Mode = SlideTransitionMode.SlideUpFadeIn;
                ITransition transition = slideTransition.GetTransition(TextBlockBorder);
                transition.Completed += delegate { transition.Stop(); 
                explanationText.Text = "";
                transition.Begin();
```

In XAML :

```
<Border x:Name="TextBlockBorder" 
                                Margin="4,0,4,5" 
                                Height="200" 
                                VerticalAlignment="Bottom" 
                                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                                BorderThickness="1" 
                                BorderBrush="White" Background="#d5e1f3" 
                                Visibility="Collapsed">
                <ScrollViewer x:Name="ScrollViewer"
                              Margin="5"
                              HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
                              VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Margin="8">

                    <TextBlock Text="Explain : " />
                    <TextBlock x:Name="explainText"
                               Text="{Binding TextExplain}" />
                </StackPanel>
                </ScrollViewer>
            </Border>
```

Here when its `Sliding Up the text becomes blurr and then becomes normal`, how to fix this? is this a bug ?

I am working on windows phone 8 app.

Comment: I just noticed the same issue, its surprising now body else has this issue. I tried the textblock within grid and still has the same issue.

Comment: Here is my version of the problem, I have a popup contains a user control, in control i have a grid and an inner grid with scrollviewer. there are some textblocks in inner grid and some in outer grid. i am setting all text dynamically, which makes textblocks within scrollbiewer blur but textblocks out of scrollviewer remains sharp. Therefore this problem has multiple dimensions.